# Difference speed between physical machiner/virtual machine for a LDAP connection in VBA

Tags: windows, vba, ldap, virtual-machine, ms-access-2013

I'm currently working on a access project in which I have to search different users and groups in a LDAP server. I use vba code to do that.

To test my application I ran it with Access 2013 in a physical machine and in a virtual machine.

I noted that my VM is 3x faster than my physical machine to establish a connection with the LDAP server (This is an Active Directory). 
Do you have any ideas why ?

My VM run with VMware Workstation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be that it does not take the same network route to reach the LDAP server.